# Beam Pubsub code is struck and not publishing the messages

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am writing Apache beam python code which read data from pubsub subscription and print it on console but it is getting struck and not getting completed.

```
import argparse
import logging
import ast
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


class FlattenJson(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Element: {element}")
class DecodeMsgs(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        print("############Before Decode:element",element)
        logging.info("Before Decode: {element}")
        return [element]
class PubsubStreamingToBq:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def run(self, subscription, pipeline_args=None):
        pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True)
        print("Args: {pipeline_args}", pipeline_args)
        with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
            pubsub_logs = (p | "Read Pubsub Msg" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription) | "Decoding" >> beam.ParDo(DecodeMsgs()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--subscription', required=True)
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    print("Known Args: {known_args}", known_args)
    PubsubStreamingToBq_obj = PubsubStreamingToBq()
    PubsubStreamingToBq_obj.run(known_args.subscription, pipeline_args)
```

Could anyone let me know what is the issue?
Using beam version 2.27.0 and Python version 3.6

Comment: Can anyone help here ?

Comment: Are you using direct runner or dataflow runner? At which part is the pipeline getting stuck. Is it not reading from pubsub?